# Can I get time of web page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do a pre-loading for a website:

- I want to create a loading page/image/etc. to show before the actual
  page is loaded.
- Nice would be something like a spinner/loading-bar
- The pre-loader shell vanish when the actual page is fully loaded

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you Googled the subject? What were the problems you ran into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if all elements of webpage are loaded.
You can use JQuery, for example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // something here
})
```

From jQuery documentation:

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready()
>   or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the
>   window or to more specific items, like images.

Comment: .load() or .ready() ?

Comment: If so, `$(window).load( function(){...} )` is better, because `$(document).ready()` occurs before images are loaded.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your programming skills, but if you are aware of javascript and jQuery you could easily try this tutorial:
http://avexdesigns.com/create-a-jquery-preloader/

The Plugin you will find here: http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jpreloader-a-preloading-screen-to-preload-images/

and all about jquery is found here: http://jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have a progressbar in ur webpage before loading ur actual content.
Refer the link below.

http://tutorialzine.com/2013/09/quick-tip-progress-bar/